# Place float elements in a row in div container

Tags: css

I'm trying to place a calender inside a transparent div container, however I'm having some issues, i want each calender box to form a row that takes up 100% in width in the transparent box. So basically at the moment the page looks like this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k261k.png).

What you probably noticed is if you look at container with the "click on the images text" is that the box is wider than the rows under it.

This is the CSS code for the calender: Basically everything relating to  .transbox has something to do with the transparent box. The calender days are the classes .weekdayssttart and weekdays. The remaining classes are the calender days with numbering. So since there is 7 days a week i just thought that I had to divide 100/7 which is 14.2857142857 and set each box type to that width in percentage. However this is the result i get: [screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiRkz.png). What I obviously notice is that the row is to small to contain the calender boxes, does anyone have an idea to fix this? Sorry for my bad english.

```css
.transbox {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    position: relative;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    overflow: auto;
}

.transbox p {
    color: darkslategray;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
    font-size:13px;
}

.transbox img {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.weekdaysstart {
    width: 14%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:floralwhite;
    border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
}

.weekdays {
    width: 14%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:floralwhite;
    border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
    text-align:center;
    float: left;
}

.hint {
    width: 99%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color:floralwhite;
    border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 5px;
   
}

.one {  
  background-color: floralwhite;
  width: 14%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
  color: darkslategrey;  
    
}

.nextrow {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  width: 14%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  clear:left;
  border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
  color: darkslategrey;
  

}

.nextmonth { 
  background-color: floralwhite;
  width: 14%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
  color: darkslategrey; 
}

.lastrow {
  width: 14%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
  color: darkslategrey;
  background-color: floralwhite;
  margin-bottom:2%;
}

.pancakes {
    width: 14%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    background: url(images/pancakes.jpeg);
    background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
}

.meatballs {
    width: 14%;
    height: 100px;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid darkslategrey;
    background: url(images/kotbulls.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Tasty recipes</title>
 <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="recipes.html">RECIPES</a></li>
  <li><a href="calendar.html">CALENDAR</a></li>
  <li class="tastyrecipes">Tasty Recipes</li>
 </ul>
 <h1>Calendar</h1>
 <h3>November 2017</h3>
    <div class = "transbox">
 <div class="hint">
  <p>Click on the image of a dish to go to its recipe-page.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="weekdaysstart">
  <p>Monday</p>
 </div>
 <div class="weekdays">
  <p>Tuesday</p>
 </div>
 <div class="weekdays">
  <p>Wednesday</p>
 </div>
 <div class="weekdays">
  <p>Thursday</p>
 </div>
 <div class="weekdays">
  <p>Friday</p>
 </div>
 <div class="weekdays">
  <p>Saturday</p>
 </div>
 <div class="weekdays">
  <p>Sunday</p>
 </div>
 <div class="nextrow">
  <p>30</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>31</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>1</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>2</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>3</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>4</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>5</p>
 </div>
 <div class="nextrow">
  <p>6</p>
 </div>
    <a href="meatballs.html">
 <div class="meatballs">
  <p>7</p>
 </div>
    </a>
 <div class="one">
  <p>8</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>9</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>10</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>11</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>12</p>
 </div>
 <div class="nextrow">
  <p>13</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>14</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>15</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>16</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>17</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>18</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>19</p>
 </div>
 <div class="nextrow">
  <p>20</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>21</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>22</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>23</p>
 </div>
 <div class="one">
  <p>24</p>
 </div>
    <a href="pancakes.html">
 <div class="pancakes">
  <p>25</p>
 </div>
    </a>
 <div class="one">
  <p>26</p>
 </div>
 <div class="nextrow">
  <p>27</p>
 </div>
 <div class="lastrow">
  <p>28</p>
 </div>
 <div class="lastrow">
  <p>29</p>
 </div>
 <div class="lastrow">
  <p>30</p>
 </div>
 <div class="nextmonth">
  <p>1</p>
 </div>
 <div class="nextmonth">
  <p>2</p>
 </div>
 <div class="nextmonth">
  <p>3</p>
 </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add markup to the snippet, so we have an example to play with.  Personally, rather than floats, I'd look into [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: Sorry, this was my first post to the site. I tried adding the HTML code so one should be able to experiment with the code a little bit now

Answer (score 0):

Like Matthew JohnSon said, you could do this using flexbox. I'm not totally sure, but I believe the `calc()` function will let it fit.

```
.transbox {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.weekdaysstart, .weekdays {
    width: calc(100% / 7);
}
```

**Edit**

I changed the names of the classes to those of your html classes.

Comment: It kinda works! However every element that the calendar consists of (every box) is on the same row. I searched for something like "clear" with flexbox but it doesn't seem to exist...

Comment: Try changing `flex-flow: row nowrap` into `flex-flow: row wrap`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a clearfix container per each row.
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix, and try to use flex instead of float, set each .row display: flex, and then set flex-grow: 1; flex-shrink: 1; flex-basis: auto; to the elements inside the row.